# Unity, how to fix Gradle error when building for Android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

I'm creating a very simple project in Unity, so far, all I've added are some UI elements. I am using v2022.3.0 and created new project yesterday, so this project is still very "vanilla".

I switched my build target to Android and tried to build my project, but I get a series of errors. I am building to my Google Pixel 6 phone.

When I try to build the project, I get the following:

```
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could
> not be reused, use --status for details Exception while marshalling
> C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-31\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-32\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-31\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-32\package.xml.
> Probably the SDK is read-only Exception while marshalling C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> > Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> > Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> > Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> > Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:writeReleaseAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :launcher:writeReleaseSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> 
> > Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED 29 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 28 up-to-date
> 
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

EDIT: Update - so, I tried building a new project using the 2D URP template. Built to Android, worked fine.

Then I created a new project using the 2D Mobile template. And I get the build error!

In my original project, what I had done was start with the 2D URP template and then added the "Mobile" packages using the package manager.

I should also note that I get an error that I did not pick an adaptive performance provider. So I went into Project Settings and chose the Samsung provider (I have a Google phone but Samsung is the only one listed). After selecting the Samsung option and some files load, I then see an "Android" provider also show up, however, attempting to select it fails. It says it does not work with this version of the editor. :(

I'm still lost, can't get it to build unless I remove the mobile packages, but since I'm targeting mobile phones for my game, I'm assuming I'll want those...

Comment: As a follow up, I went into Windows Explorer and changed the /SDK folder (and all children) and removed the "read only" flag. (Not sure why this is an issue, it's standard, but okay). After I did that, the gradle daemon error goes away, but I still get errors about C:\Program\Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml ===== Turns out that this directory exists, but the package.xml file does NOT exist?

Answer (score 1):

when your android build fails, there are many different things that you can do to fix it.

-First you can try setting your target and minimum api level higher (It's in
the Player Settings under Publishing)

-You can also try to Resolve or Delete your mobile dependencies, It's under
Assets/Mobile Dependency Resolver/Android Resolver/Resolve or Force Resolve or
Delete Resolved Libraries.

-Another thing you can try is, to just delete entire the Library Folder.

-Also one thing that helped me, but will only affect you, if you use the old
Mediation Package, because Unity made a new one for LevelPlay, so then just
remove the old package and install the new one. But then you have to change
your ad scripts.

Hope this helps:)